# работа с событиями плагина jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Использую в проекте плагин "air-datepicker". 
В нем есть собственные описанные события.
пример события блокирующий дни:

```
let disabledDays = [0, 6];
$('#Date').datepicker({
onRenderCell: function (date, cellType) {

    if (cellType == 'day') {
        var day = date.getDay(),
            isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;
        return {
            disabled: isDisabled
        }
    }
}}) ;
```

`$('#Date').datepicker({` вызов плагина (как Я понимаю).

`onRenderCell: function (date, cellType) {` само событие.

И так мой первый вопрос: 
Как с этим работать? в силу не опытности Я просто не понимаю.

Например, нельзя написать два события в одном `$('#Date').datepicker({` то есть код:

```
$('#Date').datepicker({
onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst){

   if (formattedDate == 1) {
        var day = date.getDay(),
            isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;
        return {
        }
    }
    };
onRenderCell: function (date, cellType) {
    if (cellType == 'day') {
        var day = date.getDay(),
            isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;
        return {
            disabled: isDisabled
        }
    }
} });
```

Не будет работать с ошибкой: `Unexpected identifier`. Почему? Я не знаю(

Вообще мне нужно, чтобы работал такой код:

```
`$('#Date').datepicker({
onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst){
        var SelectDay = date.getDay(),
       switch(SelectDay) {
           case 0:
               var BlockWeek = 4;
               break;
           case 1:
               var BlockWeek = 3;
               break;
           case 2:
               var BlockWeek = 2;
               break;
           case 3:
               var BlockWeek = 1;
               break;
           case 4:
               var BlockWeek = 0;
               break;
       },
    alert(BlockWeek);
    }});`
```

но в итоге такой код вылетает с ошибкой `Unexpected token switch`, если же заменить `,` после вар на `;` то ошибка будет: `date.getDay() it's not a function`

что Я именно делаю не так? если Я не правильно работаю изначально с этим, тогда что это? и как нужно прописывать в таких ситуациях?

P.S. Чукча не писатель, простите.

[ссылка на страницу плагина для скачки](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html)

[ссылка на пример кода](https://codepen.io/Gic0/pen/rGVqNM)

Comment: var SelectDay = date.getDay() **;** a не **,**

Comment: @Igor , если Вы прочтете до конца, то увидите, что сразу после кода, Я написал, что будет если заменить запятую

Comment: Намного проще будет, если вы добавите в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: @Cheg думаю добавил то что просили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что в аргументе `date` вы получаете строку и сразу пытаетесь получить из нее день.

Для начача нужно преобразовать полученную строку в объект времени, а потому уже применять метод `getDate()`:

```js
let disabledDays = [0, 6];
$('#Date').datepicker({
  onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
    if (cellType == 'day') {
      var day = date.getDay(),
        isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;
      return {
        disabled: isDisabled
      }
    }
  },
  onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) {
    var SelectDay = new Date(date).getDay(); // преобразовываем строку в объект времени и получаем из него день
    switch (SelectDay) {
      case 0:
        var BlockWeek = 4;
        break;
      case 1:
        var BlockWeek = 3;
        break;
      case 2:
        var BlockWeek = 2;
        break;
      case 3:
        var BlockWeek = 1;
        break;
      case 4:
        var BlockWeek = 0;
        break;
    }
    alert(BlockWeek);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="Date" type="text" name="calendar" class="datepicker-here" data-range="true" data-toggleselected="false" data-multiple-dates-separator=" - " placeholder="нажмите для выбора">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А почему тогда в функции onRenderCell, такой способ работает? И почему тут функции нужно разделять запятыми, а не точка с запятой?